# Sitefinity News Module Provider - Change Connection string

Tags: sitefinity

Is there a way to change the News module provider connection string to point to another sitefinity DB? Or it simply read it from the Data.config configuration file?

I am trying to make the News module in SiteA to read the News Content items from Site B DB.

thanks.

Comment: where is the news module configuration ? can you please post piece of code which uses database access.

Comment: I believe it reads from the dara.config connection string which is the global one. I am trying to find out if ut is possible for a module provider like the news provider to have its own connection string configuration

Comment: Ya i got it, but i was expecting piece of code which uses database. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define another db connection string in *data.config* file, then access through SF API,

```
ConfigManager configManager = Config.GetManager();
configManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;
DataConfig dataConfig = configManager.GetSection<DataConfig>();

//get the sitefinity element in the collection
ConnStringSettings SiteBConnectionStr = dataConfig.ConnectionStrings["SiteBConnectionString"];

//get the connection string
string connectionString = SiteBConnectionString.ConnectionString;
PagesConfig pagesConfig = configManager.GetSection<PagesConfig>();
```